# Scatterplots in R ggplot2 package: moving axes and changing font label sizes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate the following chart using ggplot2

[image]

The one change I'd like to make from that chart though is to give a colour to each point and its label. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
Z <- c("Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4", "Label5", "Label6", "Label7",        
"Label8", "Label9", "Label10", "Label11", "Label12", "Label13", "Label14",
"Label15", "Label16", "Label17", "Label18", "Label19", "Label20", "Label21",
"Label22", "Label23", "Label24")

X <- c(10.32582421, 9.772686421, -13.99202201, 3.803952545, 7.775395482,
-11.82234956, -24.27906403, -6.864457678, -24.62853773, 15.3562638,
-6.476057462, 9.576414602, -5.504090215, 29.74512913, 9.046116821,
15.79954557, -39.61679645, -0.90307239, 21.12503086, 15.30221473, 
13.40781808, -6.803226537, -4.045907666, -0.134057007)

Y <- c(0.037608141, 0.010581738, 0.117730985, 0.022347258, 0.069347278, 
0.026699666, 0.028739498, 0.040611306, 0.036626248, 0.034854158,
0.039310836, 0.03122964, 0.009422296, 0.021935924, 0.050006846, 
0.036285691, 0.016796701, 0.057764277, 0.028421772, 0.042726693,
0.037513217, 0.058422072, 0.066859355, 0.078158403)

mychart <- data.frame(Z, X, Y)

q <- ggplot(mychart, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = Z)) + theme_bw()
direct.label(q)
```

And I get the following result:

[image]

There are three things I'm having trouble figure out:

1. I'd like to remove the grey quadrant lines.
2. I'd like to move the axes so that they are centered in the chart, with plots distributed across the 4 quadrants.
3. I'd like to reduce the label font sizes - I suspect that's why some of them don't end up close to their points.

Comment: (1) `help("theme")`. (2) either look at `geom_vline()` or facet the plot with no margins; (3) `help("apply.method")` or use `geom_text()` with manual positioning vs `directlabel`; (4) your answer is not reproducible.

Comment: see also the online [help for theme](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
   panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))`
2. Use `+xlim(min,max)` and `+ylim(min,max)` to set the axis limits for your plot. Then you can use `+geom_hline(y=yvalue)` and `+geom_vline(x=xvalue)` to add the horizontal and vertical lines to your plot to designate the four quadrants.
3. Instead of using `+direct.label(q)`, use `+geom_text(aes(label=q,size=sizevalue)`,where 'sizevalue' is a numeric value that determines the size of the labels (so you can experiment with this).

EDIT: Try this code, which should fix your point labels. (I don't know of a way to move the axis labels up to the lines you drew in, nor a native way to simply move the original axes into the center of your plot. Sorry!):

```
ggplot(mychart, aes(X, Y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = Z)) + 
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          panel.background = element_blank(), 
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + 
    xlim(-40,40) + 
    ylim(0,0.12) + 
    geom_hline(y=0.04) + 
    geom_vline(y=0) + 
    geom_text(aes(x=X,y=Y+0.003,label=Z,color=Z)) + 
    theme(legend.position="none")
```

EDIT 2: Jitter in geom_text

```
ggplot(mychart, aes(X, Y, colour=Z)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          panel.background = element_blank(), 
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + 
    geom_text(aes(label=Z),
              position = position_jitter(width=2, height=0.005)) +
    xlim(-40,40) + 
    ylim(0,0.12) + 
    geom_hline(y=0.04) + 
    geom_vline(y=0) + 
    theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's the result based on your answer: http://i.imgur.com/0xMgYra.jpg


I have a couple of issues though. How do I move the axis labels to those lines?


Regarding point #3, I get the following error: "invalid argument to unary operator"

Comment: Added a fix to my response based on the plot you showed. Let me know if that edit works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. This does help a bit. The reason why I used the directlabels package's command direct.label is to fix overlapping labels. Is there another way to minimize this? Picture of current output: http://i.imgur.com/6xEMcwu.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I'm having trouble getting directlabels to work properly.  However, I've added a new edit to the answer that gives one option using "jitter" in geom_text (you'll want to mess with the jitter parameters to see if you can get a plot that works for you).

Comment: Thanks for all your help rhozzy. It doesn't look to me that we could further improve on it. At the end of the day, no algorithm can match the human eye in determining the best way to avoid overlapping labels.